# Is there a way in python 3 to make it so that two user defined functions only require input once

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, user-defined-functions

Lets say i have two user defined functions `monthly_salary()` and `report()` in Python 3

```
def monthly_salary():
    monthly_salary = int(input('Enter Monthly Salary'))
    return monthly_salary

def report():
    yearly_salary = monthly_salary() * 12

    message = '%s %4d %s %6d' % ('John gets paid monthly salary of', monthly_salary(), '& yearly salary of', yearly_salary)

    print(message)
```

If I run the above code, it will ask the user monthly user twice. Is there a way to make it so that it only ask the user monthly salary once?

Comment: Hint: how are you *already* making it so that when you format the `message`, you don't have to do the `monthly_salary() * 12` calculation again? Do the same thing so that you don't have to repeat the `monthly_salary()` calculation.

Comment: Don't call the function twice if you don't need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code asks for input twice since you call monthly_salary() twice. 
Change your code to store in a variable and use this for further calculations.

```
def monthly_salary(): 
    return int(input('Enter Monthly Salary: '))

def report():
    m_salary = monthly_salary()

    message = '%s %4d %s %6d' % ('John gets paid monthly salary of', m_salary, '& yearly salary of', m_salary * 12)

    print(message)

report()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the monthly salary in a variable and use that variable.